# Given $F_y - \frac{d}{dx} F_{y'} + \frac{d^2}{dx^2}F_{y''}=0$ where $F$ has no $x$ dependence, show that the first integral is of the form.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, calculus-of-variations

> Given $\displaystyle F_y - \frac{d}{dx} F_{y'} + \frac{d^2}{dx^2}F_{y''}=0$ (where $y\in C_4$) ,  if $F(x,y,y',y'')$ does not depend on $x$ explicitly, then the system has the first integral $\displaystyle y''F_{y''} -y'\left(\frac{d}{dx}F_{y''}-F_y\right)=C.$

I've tried expanding out $\displaystyle F_y - \frac{d}{dx} F_{y'} + \frac{d^2}{dx^2}F_{y''}$ by $\displaystyle \frac{d}{dx}F_{y'}= \frac{dF}{dx}+\frac{dF}{dy}y' + \frac{dF}{dy'}y'' + \frac{dF}{dy''}y'''$ (and a similar way for $\displaystyle \frac{d^2}{dx^2}F_{y''}$, and using the fact that there is no explicit x-dependence, then $\displaystyle \frac{dF}{dx} = 0$. But with this method, things don't seem to cancel out nicely in such a way that after I integrate with respect to $x$, I obtain the result I seek.

Another thing i've noted is that I can express what I start with as $\displaystyle F_{y'} = \frac{d}{dx}\left(F_{y'}-\frac{d}{dx}F_{y''}\right)$ and what I need to show as $\displaystyle F-y''F_{y''}+C = y'\left(F_{y'}-\frac{d}{dx}F_{y''}\right)$, so i've tried integrating $\displaystyle F_{y'} = \frac{d}{dx}\left(F_{y'}-\frac{d}{dx}F_{y''}\right)$ from the start, so that $\displaystyle \int F_{y'}dx = F_{y'}+\frac{d}{dx}F_{y''} + C$.

Am I approaching this right? Any idea how to proceed?

Comment: The equation you are managing is the Euler-Lagrange equation for a lagrangian in higher derivatives than usually (in Physics only until the first derivative). The lagrangians without explicit dependence on the free variable have the energy conserved. With this idea I don't get that first integral, but this one: $$ y''F_{y''} -y'\left(\frac{d}{dx}F_{y''}-F_y\right)=F+C$$ I am not saying you wrote it wrong because I didn't integrate the equation, but this gives an idea to follow...

Comment: @boba : You wrote : "show that the first integral is of the form...". The first integral of what ? with respect to what variable ?

Comment: Since Boba didn't answer to my comment in order to clarify his question which remains ambiguous and so without solution, I vote to close his question.